# Azure Storage Sync with Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I am following 
[this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-blob-storage/) 
& 
[this one](https://blog.xamarin.com/sync-files-between-devices-azure-file-sync/) 
to use Azure Storage Sync in my xamarin forms app.

Testing the app on iOS so far.

The following code executes fine

```
// FILES: Creating/Adding file
MobileServiceFile file = await this.monkeyTable.AddFileAsync(monkey, Path.GetFileName(targetPath));
```

but the file object received does not have ParentId or StoreUri values. They are both null.

What's missing?

Will they both get updated when I sync the offline table to azure? If so how do I make use of the StoreUri property before the sync is triggered?

The idea is to save the URI property in my custom object to use it online on a companion web app.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks 
ST

Comment: As far as I know, the `AddFileAsync` operation is working completely offline. In order to persist file changes (upload/delete files), you can invoke the `PushFileChangesAsync` method on your table. What do you mean that "save the URI property in my custom object to use it online on a companion web app." ? Did you mean that generating the online URL for the file before `PushFileChangesAsync` is invoked?

Comment: I understand that AddFileAsync is completely working offline. What I need to do is to be able to work offline & have some way of getting a URL to the storage that I can then save along with the object which is using this storage. So when I do push Async, I have the URL of the storage, along with the object it was used with online, to use it to show the file on web.

Comment: As far as I know, the StoreUri would look like this: https://<yourStorageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/<tableName>-<parentId>/<fileName>. But the value of ParentId is null before you syncing the offline table to azure.

Comment: at what instance does the ParentId property MobileServiceFile is generated? 
When we create the file using the code above or when we call PushFileChangesAsync?